# how to separate and display multiple checkbox data value from one post custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I am using post custom fields in my theme and in my custom fields I have multiple checkbox selection options.

After selecting multiple checkboxes and saving, here is the custom field saved data format :

`english| hindi| chhattisgarhi| tamil| telgu| malayalam| kannada| punjabi| gujarati| marathi| urdu| bengali| odia| other`.

Now when I print this custom field in my single.php with this code :

```
<?php the_field('languages'); ?>
```

I am getting this type of value :

**Language** : `english| hindi| chhattisgarhi| tamil| telgu| malayalam| kannada| punjabi| gujarati| marathi| urdu| bengali| odia| other`.

But I want this type of output if I select multiple checkboxes :

**Language** : `english, hindi, chhattisgarhi, tamil, telgu, malayalam, kannada, punjabi, gujarati, marathi, urdu, bengali, odia, other`.

And if I select only 1 checkbox, then :

**Language** : `English`

can any one help with this?

thanks

Comment: To the person who downvoted, please add a comment why you downvoted. Simply downvoting without a comment is not helpful.

Comment: @waterloomatt It wasn't me, but I can understand why it would have been downvoted. The question shows no attempt to solve the issue themselves and no evidence of having even tried, and doesn't even include any code. All of these are a requirement for this site. While a comment is helpful, site policy to downvote questions that do not meet the site guidelines. In this case its pretty obvious that the question doesn't meet the basic guidelines for asking as discussed in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want get result ..._field() function you should use get_field() then you can make next operations on returned data like str_replace(). Please go to body both functions and compare their end part, one has return $xxx; and the other has echo $xxx;

```
<?php the_field("languages"); ?>
```

And second:

```
<?php echo get_field("languages"); ?>
```

Do you can use:

```
<?php echo str_replace("|",",",get_field("languages")); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to go about this. You can simply replace all pipes (|) with a comma (,) because it looks like there is already a space after each pipe.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
<?php
echo str_replace('|', ',', the_field('languages'));
```

The other way would be to explode the string into an array and them glue them back together using a separator.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
<?php 
$elements = explode('|', the_field('languages'));
echo $implode(',', $elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Second answer's logic is perfectly right according to me but as he used the_field i guess it will give the error so if you got the error use get_field function.

For an instance

```
 echo str_replace('|', ',', get_field('languages'));
```